# How to preserve text format when return in nodejs/express?

Tags: node.js, express, format

Here is a text file in console output on nodejs/express backend server and it carries neat format:

```
 abi: [
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "_value",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "_itemName",
                                "type": "string"
                        },
...
]
```

When the file above is received in mobile front end (React Native), it becomes:

```
 abi: '[\n\t{\n\t\t"inputs": [\n\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\t"internalType": "uint256",\n\t\t\t\t"name": "_value",\n\t\t\t\t"type": "uint256"\n\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\t"internalType": "string",\n\t\t\t\t"name": "_itemName",\n\t\t\t\t"type":...]'
```

The format and content of the text file has been changed by addition of `\n` and `\t` and it can't be used as input for a function call. Is there way the original nice and neat format can be preserved or restored when returned from a nodejs server?

UPDATE:

The text string is returned on nodejs/express server as json format:

```
return res.status(200).send({dude:_dude.deploy_address, fex:_fex.deploy_address, forsale:{abi:_forsale.abi, bytecode:_forsale.bytecode}});
```

Here is the `fetch` from the mobile:

```
let res = await fetch(beUrl, {method: "GET", headers: {
                                                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
                                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
                                              }});
let res1 = await res.json();
```

Comment: Can you post the parts of code where you send and request the data?

Comment: The latter is probably just the Javascript string form of the first form.  `\n` just means newline and `\t` is a tab.

Comment: Post updated. It seems that the white space, new line and tab are not interpreted properly on mobile end. Not sure which part causes it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the format was reserved and restored:

On nodejs/express server, JSON.stringift the whole return object:

```
let obj = JSON.stringify({dude:_dude.deploy_address, fex:_fex.deploy_address, forsale:{abi:(_forsale.abi), bytecode:(_forsale.bytecode)}});
    return res.status(200).send(obj);
```

On front end, JSON.parse the abi and bytecode:

```
let res = await fetch(beUrl, {method: "GET", headers: {
                                                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
                                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
                                              }});
      let res1 = await res.json();
      let res3 = JSON.parse(res1.forsale.abi);
      let res4 = JSON.parse(res1.forsale.bytecode);
```

res3 and res4 have the text format restored to its original as it is on the nodejs/express server.